# Select multiple contacts Android

Tags: java, android

I need to select multiple contacts from my cell phone for my android application. I have searched at many websites but there nobody has proposed a built in solution. The URI allows me to select a single contact but I want to open a view of contacts with check boxes. Any help would be highly appreciated in this regard.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html